# ExchangeEWS throws ErrorCalendarOccurrenceIndexIsOutOfRecurrenceRange when I'm trying to get an existing occurence by index

Tags: exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2007

I have the strange situation: 
I created recurring calendar event by Exchange web service using the request like this:

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:mes="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" 
    xmlns:typ="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
      <soapenv:Header>
        <typ:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2007_SP1"/>
        <typ:ExchangeImpersonation>
          <typ:ConnectingSID>
            <typ:PrimarySmtpAddress>someuser@clab.local</typ:PrimarySmtpAddress>
          </typ:ConnectingSID>
        </typ:ExchangeImpersonation>
      </soapenv:Header>
      <soapenv:Body>
    <mes:CreateItem MessageDisposition="SaveOnly" SendMeetingInvitations="SendToAllAndSaveCopy">
          <mes:Items>
            <typ:CalendarItem>
              <typ:Subject>QC42135 test 3</typ:Subject>
              <typ:Body BodyType="HTML"/>
              <typ:Importance>Normal</typ:Importance>
              <typ:ReminderIsSet>false</typ:ReminderIsSet>
              <typ:Start>2014-07-25T04:00:00-05:00</typ:Start>
              <typ:End>2014-07-25T05:00:00-05:00</typ:End>
              <typ:Location/>
              <typ:IsResponseRequested>false</typ:IsResponseRequested>
              <typ:RequiredAttendees>
                <typ:Attendee>
                  <typ:Mailbox>
                    <typ:EmailAddress>user1@clab.local</typ:EmailAddress>
                  </typ:Mailbox>
                </typ:Attendee>
              </typ:RequiredAttendees>
              <typ:Recurrence>
                <typ:WeeklyRecurrence>
                  <typ:Interval>2</typ:Interval>
                  <typ:DaysOfWeek>Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday Sunday</typ:DaysOfWeek>
                </typ:WeeklyRecurrence>
                <typ:EndDateRecurrence>
                  <typ:StartDate>2014-07-20</typ:StartDate>
                  <typ:EndDate>2014-07-30</typ:EndDate>
                </typ:EndDateRecurrence>
              </typ:Recurrence>
              <typ:MeetingTimeZone TimeZoneName="FLE Standard Time"/>
            </typ:CalendarItem>
          </mes:Items>
        </mes:CreateItem>
      </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Series of occurences were successfully created:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Header>
      <t:ServerVersionInfo MajorVersion="8" MinorVersion="3" MajorBuildNumber="348" MinorBuildNumber="2" Version="Exchange2007_SP1" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"/>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <m:CreateItemResponse xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
         <m:ResponseMessages>
            <m:CreateItemResponseMessage ResponseClass="Success">
               <m:ResponseCode>NoError</m:ResponseCode>
               <m:Items>
                  <t:CalendarItem>
                     <t:ItemId Id="AAMkADVmYWI5YjhjLTdiN2MtNDJjNi04ZWIzLTUzNjVjZjk1MWY5OQBGAAAAAACuKk855hnzQ7gDOBltDFd1BwAa27cU8ukoS5yPRueWn38YAAobNHU+AAAa27cU8ukoS5yPRueWn38YAHDq5rCGAAA=" ChangeKey="DwAAABYAAAAa27cU8ukoS5yPRueWn38YAHDq52bj"/>
                  </t:CalendarItem>
               </m:Items>
            </m:CreateItemResponseMessage>
         </m:ResponseMessages>
      </m:CreateItemResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

But when I'm trying to get occurrences of the event 
by index right after creation I'm able to get only first occurrence. For the others I receive ErrorCalendarOccurrenceIndexIsOutOfRecurrenceRange.

Here is GetItem request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:typ="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:mes="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
<soapenv:Header><typ:RequestServerVersion   Version="Exchange2007_SP1"/>
    <typ:ExchangeImpersonation>
      <typ:ConnectingSID>
        <typ:PrimarySmtpAddress>someuser@clab.local</typ:PrimarySmtpAddress>
      </typ:ConnectingSID>
    </typ:ExchangeImpersonation>
</soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
      <mes:GetItem>
         <mes:ItemShape>
            <typ:BaseShape>IdOnly</typ:BaseShape>
        </mes:ItemShape>
         <mes:ItemIds>
            <typ:OccurrenceItemId RecurringMasterId="AAMkADVmYWI5YjhjLTdiN2MtNDJjNi04ZWIzLTUzNjVjZjk1MWY5OQBGAAAAAACuKk855hnzQ7gDOBltDFd1BwAa27cU8ukoS5yPRueWn38YAAobNHU+AAAa27cU8ukoS5yPRueWn38YAHDq5rCGAAA=" ChangeKey="DwAAABYAAAAa27cU8ukoS5yPRueWn38YAHDq52bj" InstanceIndex="1" />
             <typ:OccurrenceItemId RecurringMasterId="AAMkADVmYWI5YjhjLTdiN2MtNDJjNi04ZWIzLTUzNjVjZjk1MWY5OQBGAAAAAACuKk855hnzQ7gDOBltDFd1BwAa27cU8ukoS5yPRueWn38YAAobNHU+AAAa27cU8ukoS5yPRueWn38YAHDq5rCGAAA=" ChangeKey="DwAAABYAAAAa27cU8ukoS5yPRueWn38YAHDq52bj" InstanceIndex="2" />
             <typ:OccurrenceItemId RecurringMasterId="AAMkADVmYWI5YjhjLTdiN2MtNDJjNi04ZWIzLTUzNjVjZjk1MWY5OQBGAAAAAACuKk855hnzQ7gDOBltDFd1BwAa27cU8ukoS5yPRueWn38YAAobNHU+AAAa27cU8ukoS5yPRueWn38YAHDq5rCGAAA=" ChangeKey="DwAAABYAAAAa27cU8ukoS5yPRueWn38YAHDq52bj" InstanceIndex="3" />
             <typ:OccurrenceItemId RecurringMasterId="AAMkADVmYWI5YjhjLTdiN2MtNDJjNi04ZWIzLTUzNjVjZjk1MWY5OQBGAAAAAACuKk855hnzQ7gDOBltDFd1BwAa27cU8ukoS5yPRueWn38YAAobNHU+AAAa27cU8ukoS5yPRueWn38YAHDq5rCGAAA=" ChangeKey="DwAAABYAAAAa27cU8ukoS5yPRueWn38YAHDq52bj" InstanceIndex="4" />
             <typ:OccurrenceItemId RecurringMasterId="AAMkADVmYWI5YjhjLTdiN2MtNDJjNi04ZWIzLTUzNjVjZjk1MWY5OQBGAAAAAACuKk855hnzQ7gDOBltDFd1BwAa27cU8ukoS5yPRueWn38YAAobNHU+AAAa27cU8ukoS5yPRueWn38YAHDq5rCGAAA=" ChangeKey="DwAAABYAAAAa27cU8ukoS5yPRueWn38YAHDq52bj" InstanceIndex="5" />

         </mes:ItemIds>
      </mes:GetItem>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And response

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Header>
      <t:ServerVersionInfo MajorVersion="8" MinorVersion="3" MajorBuildNumber="348" MinorBuildNumber="2" Version="Exchange2007_SP1" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"/>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <m:GetItemResponse xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
         <m:ResponseMessages>
            <m:GetItemResponseMessage ResponseClass="Success">
               <m:ResponseCode>NoError</m:ResponseCode>
               <m:Items>
                  <t:CalendarItem>
                     <t:ItemId Id="AAMkADVmYWI5YjhjLTdiN2MtNDJjNi04ZWIzLTUzNjVjZjk1MWY5OQFRAAiI0XGjJ/YgAEYAAAAAripPOeYZ80O4AzgZbQxXdQcAGtu3FPLpKEucj0bnlp9/GAAKGzR1PgAAGtu3FPLpKEucj0bnlp9/GABw6uawhgAAEA==" ChangeKey="DwAAABYAAAAa27cU8ukoS5yPRueWn38YAHDq52bj"/>
                  </t:CalendarItem>
               </m:Items>
            </m:GetItemResponseMessage>
            <m:GetItemResponseMessage ResponseClass="Error">
               <m:MessageText>Occurrence index is out of recurrence range.</m:MessageText>
               <m:ResponseCode>ErrorCalendarOccurrenceIndexIsOutOfRecurrenceRange</m:ResponseCode>
               <m:DescriptiveLinkKey>0</m:DescriptiveLinkKey>
               <m:Items/>
            </m:GetItemResponseMessage>
            <m:GetItemResponseMessage ResponseClass="Error">
               <m:MessageText>Occurrence index is out of recurrence range.</m:MessageText>
               <m:ResponseCode>ErrorCalendarOccurrenceIndexIsOutOfRecurrenceRange</m:ResponseCode>
               <m:DescriptiveLinkKey>0</m:DescriptiveLinkKey>
               <m:Items/>
            </m:GetItemResponseMessage>
            <m:GetItemResponseMessage ResponseClass="Error">
               <m:MessageText>Occurrence index is out of recurrence range.</m:MessageText>
               <m:ResponseCode>ErrorCalendarOccurrenceIndexIsOutOfRecurrenceRange</m:ResponseCode>
               <m:DescriptiveLinkKey>0</m:DescriptiveLinkKey>
               <m:Items/>
            </m:GetItemResponseMessage>
            <m:GetItemResponseMessage ResponseClass="Error">
               <m:MessageText>Occurrence index is out of recurrence range.</m:MessageText>
               <m:ResponseCode>ErrorCalendarOccurrenceIndexIsOutOfRecurrenceRange</m:ResponseCode>
               <m:DescriptiveLinkKey>0</m:DescriptiveLinkKey>
               <m:Items/>
            </m:GetItemResponseMessage>
         </m:ResponseMessages>
      </m:GetItemResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I found the description of recurring event on Microsoft site http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633684%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx
and according the documentation when a recurring series is created, each occurrence item has as index that represents its position in the series. 
The index starts at one and advances by one for each item in the series. But it seems to be incorrect. 
In my case obviously occurrences are indexed in different way. 
Can anyone explain how Exchange indexes occurrences? How can I get certain occurrence in the series?

Comment: I tried to reproduce your case, but it took me too long. What I would look at is your impersonation piece and the folder you are actually creating the item in. When I was testing I accidentally had left one of your email adresses in, I saw the recurring event in my Outlook, but EWS *failed* to retrieve the occurrences with an ordinary FindItems call. I suggest you try to get that to work first (FindItems should return the occurrences). Do it first without invitations etc, then build complexity.

Comment: InstanceIndex does indeed start at and increase by 1 - that's not where the error is.